# QGIS export GeoTIFF with Gdal2xyz loses elevation

Tags: qgis, gdal2xyz

I am new to QGIS.
I need to create a textfile with X,Y,Z coordinates in UTM (WGS84 or ED1950) from LiDAR terrain data that are provided to me as a GeoTIFF file with a 1 m resolution. The TIFF is using Belgian Lambert 1972 as the coordinate system. Unfortunately, Belgian government is still using this old system and the terrain data are always in Lambert 1972.

So in QGIS I open the file (raster) and since it is a vast area, a few hundred of square km with millions of points (given the 1x1m resolution), I clip it to just the area that interests me, which is maybe 1 or 2 km².

Then using the Gdal2xyz tool I exported it to an x,y,z file which has all the coordinates in its original format: Lambert 1972. So I +/- 200000 rows like this.

```
234300,5;118333,5;208,01
234301,5;118333,5;207,73
234302,5;118333,5;208,255
234303,5;118333,5;208,35
234304,5;118333,5;208,18
```

Which is great, but I need it in UTM because the textfile will be used in other geographic and surveying software that is referenced to UTM.

It looked easy enough, I exported the clipped area to a new GeoTIFF file, while indicating the new Coordinate Reference system (UTM31 - ED50). And with the Gdal2xyz tool I exported it again to an x,y,z file

In this export however, the elevation is gone (or it is put to -9999 which means "no data") everywhere.

```
681697.162,5583092.410,-9999
681698.145,5583092.410,-9999
681699.127,5583092.410,-9999
681700.110,5583092.410,-9999
681701.092,5583092.410,-9999
```

I have tried for hours every possible way of changing the CRS but no matter what I try: I lose the elevation. I just don't understand why this doesn't happen if I export it in its original format, Lambert 1972. The TIFF file in UTM does have the elevation because I can apply hillshading and see the valleys and hills. But exporting to x,y,z : no way...

You can download an example of the GeoTIFF (in Lambert 1972) here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7kjxzsazfsw8fw1/Clip%20PLP%20Valley%20only%20in%20LT%2072.tif?dl=1

Comment: oh and I forgot to mention: I also tried the Translate tool with output to an xyz file. The result is the same: elevation is -9999 everywhere...

Comment: You warp the image from EPSG:31370 into EPSG:23031, is that right? Warping rotates the original image so that the result looks like here https://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/20151028b_nu1.png. As a result there are four triangles at the corners full of nodata. If you look further in your XYZ file you should see real height values like this `682098.571162079461 5583093.30862579495 216.149993896484375`.

Comment: YES! I feel silly now.  Indeed changing the projection, rotates the grid slightly. And if I scroll further down in the XYZ file, I do see elevations (beginning at row 923). 
Now, I'm new to this kind of geotif file. So it is not something where each point has an x,y,z coordinate because then it would be possible to translate each point/coordinate to another coordinate system and maintain the corresponding Z-value. I understand that the TIF is more like a 2D table where each pixel has x,y coordinates and a value, which is the elevation. 
You saved my day! Many thanks

Comment: on second thought: does this mean that the height values are no longer at their original geographical positions? I mean they stay at their position but the image shifts/rotates? 
I've tried to see it;changing from Lambert to UTM will result in a minimal rotation so it's hard to tell. Not that important, but on a larger scale and/or when transforming between projections that have a bigger impact, it could be a problem

Comment: If you re-project your whole input DEM into EPSG:23031 first and cut the rectangular pieces from that image you will get xyz files full of data as long as you work in the middle of the big DEM. You are right that TIFF and xyz https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html are like a 2D tables. But every point in the source data is translated into another coordinate system with Z-value. It is just that for filling the north-up envelope of the warped data some new dummy points must be created.

Comment: The original file has height values at nodes of a regular grid. The re-projected DEM has also a regular grid but that is different and points are not exactly at their original places. By default GDAL is using a nearest neighbor resampling and if the grid size (pixel size) in source and target are the same and projections are about the same then the points are shifted by half a pixel at maximum. There are other resampling methods (average, bilinear, cubic...) that can suit better than NN for some other use cases.

Comment: Have you tried using Raster Pixels to Points? That will create a shapefile of points which might be easier to transform to UTM.

Comment: I will check it! TX